# Same or different login password for each server instances in a server cluster

Tags: password

If we make a server for an application (game or mobile app, etc.), we actually set up a cluster of many identical server instances and/or a network load balancer.

For maximum security, setting a different login password for each server instance is better, I guess. However, it will be cumbersome.

In real field, do you set different login password for each server instace, even if the number of server instances are more than 100?

Answer (score 0):

You typically try to set up all unique systems with (the hashed values of)  unique random strong  root / local Administrator passwords (and keep the passwords secure with a break glass set up for emergencies (see for instance [this](https://hipaa.yale.edu/security/break-glass-procedure-granting-emergency-access-critical-ephi-systems)) .

You then try to never need to use that password.

Maybe you use your configuration management tooling to then maintain additional local user accounts for your administrators, each with their own personal passwords and/or public ssh keys, but typically you set up a form of centralized authentication and authorization and enroll all your servers into that.

Then you only have a single logical place to maintain the accounts and privileges  of joiners, leavers, users and administrators.  Administrators (and users) will normally be able to use that central authentication and their own personal username/password combination to get access to all the systems they need to perform their duties using a single account, with always the same password everywhere  (and ideally a multi factor challenge as well for critical tasks).

Answer (score 0):

load balancer (number of them for HA) usually goes in front of your cluster (instances)

personally i would go with:

- unique root password for every server even if i have 10 000 of them (use KeePass or similar to keep it secure and to organize)
- SSH public key authentication within your secure network perimeter (behind VPN/firewall)
- OpenLDAP (slapd, libnss-ldap, libpam-ldap) for AAA/SSO if necessary